# convert string to private and public key (RSA)

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, encode

The two strings that are the private and public keys are :

```
    static String Public =          
       "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDH+wPrKYG1KVlzQUVtBghR8n9d" + "/n" +
     "zcShSZo0+3KgyVdOea7Ei7vQ1U4wRn1zlI5rSqHDzFitblmqnB2anzVvdQxLQ3Uq" + "/n" +
    "EBKBfMihnLgCSW8Xf7MCH+DSGHNvBg2xSNhcfEmnbLPLnbuz4ySn1UB0lH2eqxy5" + "/n"+
     "0zstxhTY0binD9Y+rwIDAQAB"+ "/n";
    static String Private = 
        "MIICxjBABgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wMzAbBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwDgQIr5NQ/LYPG/UCAggA" +"/n"+
      "MBQGCCqGSIb3DQMHBAiLh89iGSkmoASCAoBCpAo9/IzDE3yGhvWr9RgozE7revOo" +"/n"+
          "V2OXmU+d0+WYAAx2GYVaUCbFVrmgiVmrbiTgLUMXAGIpvxQ2rzyIvRHW/RN3Gcky" +"/n"+
        "qR/AwBatzixqrnoS4aD1/Ovjr4hwde4XHYbPEilZZuVAJFiznhy73qm/So4XghSY........." ;
```

I have read the other questions and tried their solutions but nothing worked....I have a public and private key both as strings.. I need to convert them to 'Key' but i keep getting java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException ..at generatePublic and generatePrivate functions.. also the keys are just for testing therefore, it is ok if they are known to others...

```
      public static Key loadPublicKey(String stored) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException 
       {
      byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode((stored.getBytes()));
      X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(data);
      KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
      return fact.generatePublic(spec);

        }


public static Key loadPrivateKey(String key64) throws     GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        byte[] clear = Base64.getDecoder().decode(key64.getBytes());
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(clear);
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey priv = fact.generatePrivate(keySpec);
        Arrays.fill(clear, (byte) 0);
        return priv;

   }
```

Comment: remove the line feed `+ "/n"`

Comment: still the same issue .. am getting java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: I changed the public key to :"MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDH+wPrKYG1KVlzQUVtBghR8n9dzcShSZo0+3KgyVdOea7Ei7vQ1U4wRn1zlI5rSqHDzFitblmqnB2anzVvdQxLQ3UqEBKBfMihnLgCSW8Xf7MCH+DSGHNvBg2xSNhcfEmnbLPLnbuz4ySn1UB0lH2eqxy50zstxhTY0binD9Y+rwIDAQAB"

Comment: I have tried it by my own with the public key and it is working

Comment: Line feeds are `\n`, not `/n`. In a string, this would look like `"\\n"`.

Comment: Necroed but for info: aside from the extraneous `/n`, your `Public` is indeed base64 of X.509-SPKI publickey suitable for Java `X509EncodedKeySpec`, but **your `Private` is (base64 of beginning of) an _encrypted_ PKCS8 private key** (EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo) while `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` must be _unencrypted_ or here _decrypted_. If you have the password and (can) use BouncyCastle see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932334/how-read-a-pkcs8-encrypted-private-key-which-is-also-encoded-in-der-with-bouncyc otherwise it's rather complicated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the line Feeds in the string declaration. That is not part of the key:

```
static String Public =          
       "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDH+wPrKYG1KVlzQUVtBghR8n9d" +
     "zcShSZo0+3KgyVdOea7Ei7vQ1U4wRn1zlI5rSqHDzFitblmqnB2anzVvdQxLQ3Uq" + 
    "EBKBfMihnLgCSW8Xf7MCH+DSGHNvBg2xSNhcfEmnbLPLnbuz4ySn1UB0lH2eqxy5" +
     "0zstxhTY0binD9Y+rwIDAQAB";
static String Private = 
        "MIICxjBABgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wMzAbBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwDgQIr5NQ/LYPG/UCAggA" +
      "MBQGCCqGSIb3DQMHBAiLh89iGSkmoASCAoBCpAo9/IzDE3yGhvWr9RgozE7revOo" +
          "V2OXmU+d0+WYAAx2GYVaUCbFVrmgiVmrbiTgLUMXAGIpvxQ2rzyIvRHW/RN3Gcky" +
        "qR/AwBatzixqrnoS4aD1/Ovjr4hwde4XHYbPEilZZuVAJFiznhy73qm/So4XghSY........." ;
```

I have tried it with the following code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
      System.out.println(loadPublicKey(Public));

  }

  public static Key loadPublicKey(String stored) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException 
  {
 byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode((stored.getBytes()));
 X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(data);
 KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
 return fact.generatePublic(spec);

   }
```

And Output is:

```
Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 140431102839105138202102866401190456107365606715815288536913018579006717438700259314092212104831553250527764925385527697411165705192297577022746989837839401358787285684108054389360182109284048524426941021357601686464156659759470495649944686235380003772357268264646549523784880655065600797504478771675703688879
  public exponent: 65537
```

Comment: @zaph it is a string of multiple lines .. it cannot be written as is ... unless it is all placed in one line

Comment: @HayaRaed It can not be. I have tried it by my own with public key and no exception

Comment: @Jens really!! Why am I getting.... Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DER input, Integer tag error
 at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(Unknown Source)
 at Main.loadPrivateKey(Main.java:144)
 at Main.main(Main.java:185)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DER input, Integer tag error
 at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(Unknown Source)

Comment: @HayaRaed You refer the private key part. I can not check it, because you have not shown it completly

Comment: Looks like it is a DER and not an RSA Key?

Comment: what should do for Load Private key